# AWS Redshift retrieve the UDF function Definition via SQL

Tags: amazon-web-services, function, amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions, ddl

I am trying to retrieve ***all*** UDF function definition / ddls  in a specific AWS Redshift database.
Appreciate if anyone can help with the same.

Things i tried & failed:

```
SELECT GET_DDL('FUNCTION','f_next_business_day');

SHOW FUNCTION f_next_business_day;

SELECT prosrc
FROM PG_FUNCTION
WHERE proname = 'f_next_business_day';

SELECT * from pg_catalog.pg_get_functiondef('f_next_business_day', null);

select ddl
from admin.v_generate_tbl_ddl
where schemaname = 'public' --and tablename='some_table'
order by seq asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query `SVV_REDSHIFT_FUNCTIONS` to get all the functions defined for a database. The definitions for the function reside in `pg_proc`. By joining these two tables you can get all the functions and definitions for a database

```sql
select proname,prosrc from pg_proc p inner join SVV_REDSHIFT_FUNCTIONS t on p.proname=t.function_name where t.database_name='<your_database_name>';
```

Comment: This query doesnot retrieve the custom udf's. :(

Comment: I was able to retrieve custom udfs